# Force reloading template from a Flask app?

Tags: ajax, flask

I have a Flask app where I'd like for users to see the effect of selecting a different set of parameters in real time.  So I have a slider displayed on the web page, and after the user selects a different parameter, I'd like to force a re-calculation of my model and re-display of the web page.

Here's what I tried:

In my html:

```
<div class="""slidecontainer">
         <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value={{ slider_value }} class="slider" id="myRange">
        <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
  var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
  var output = document.getElementById("demo");
  output.innerHTML = slider.value;

  var slider_value;
  slider.onchange = function() {
     output.innerHTML = this.value;
     slider_value = this.value;
     doWork();
  }
function doWork() {
    // ajax the JSON to the server
    $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '/receiver',
     data: JSON.stringify (slider_value),
     success: function(data) { alert('data: ' + data); },
     contentType: "application/json",
     dataType: 'json'
  });
}
```

In my Python app.py:

```
@app.route("/receiver", methods = ['POST','GET'])
def worker():
   # read json + reply                                                                                                                                                                           
   data = request.get_json()
   print("Data = ",data)

   new_output = my_model.calculate(data)

   return render_template("complete.html",new_output)
```

But even though I can see that when the user changes the slide value, it does get back into the Python code (because I see the "Data=..." printout), the displayed web page never gets updated with the new_output.  Is there any way to force the rendering of the template with the new output?

Thank you!

Comment: It might be better if you render the page once and then use an api to get new data, dependent upon an object change, which is then dynamically rendered to the page. For example, your JS ajax could get new information that it directly posts to the page, rather than forcing Flask to refresh the browser page (which is also a worse UI experience).
I find Vue.js really good for this (and very well documented).

Answer (score 0):

```
<p> {({ serverValue })} <p>
<input v-model="sliderValue">

<script>
    var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#vue-container',        // make sure relevant html is inside a div with id="vue-container"
        delimiters: ['{({', '})}'],  // separate Vue delimiters from JinJa2
        data: {
            serverValue: 'no initial data',
        },
        watch: {
            // whenever sliderValue changes, this function will run
            sliderValue: this.calculateServerSide();
        methods: {
            calculateServerSide: function () {
                vmObj = this;  // access Vue instance inside Ajax calls.
                $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_add_numbers', {
                    a: 10,
                    b: 20
                }, function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    vmObj.serverValue = data.result;
                });
            },
        }
    })
</script>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

an example of the sort of thing I was hinting at in my comment.